# How to decode a url in JavaScript or NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-router

In our NextJS application we have a URL that is fed with various query strings.

With some query strings, however, we have the problem that they are displayed in encoded form. For example like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/my-app/test-app?project=project%3Aone&project=project%3Atwo
```

As you can see, the colons are replaced with `%CA`.

I know that this may be a default behavior, but I need the colons in the URL.

Is there any way I can get this? So I need to URL above like:

```
http://localhost:8080/my-app/test-app?project=project:one&project=project:two
```

We are using `URLSearchParams()` like this:

```
const constructQueryString = (params: any) => {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    const projects = params.project.split(',');
    projects.forEach((p) => {
        urlSearchParams.append('project', p);
    });

    return searchParams.toString();
};
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong here, if you do `searchParams.getAll('project');` you'll see that it returns `['project:one', 'project:two']`

Comment: @Reyno But why isn't that showing up in my URL? I think it's because we are using Next.js router.push() and for this reason the URL is being adjusted again. I have no idea what I can do here to avoid that encoding.

Comment: Because an `:` is an unsafe ASCII character. It get's converted so it can safely be send over the internet. And as you can see it gets converted back when you use the `.get` or `.getAll` methods. See [HTML URL Encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) for more info

Answer (score 5):

Use the `decodeURIComponent` global function in Javascript

```js
const decodedPath = decodeURIComponent("http://localhost:8080/my-app/test-app?project=project%3Aone&project=project%3Atwo")
```

The Result is what you want as below:

```
http://localhost:8080/my-app/test-app?project=project:one&project=project:two
```

Answer (score -1):

These are escape codes for special characters in the URL that are necessary and cant be avoided. Also, there's no need for you to use URLSearchParams. Just use `router.query` will give you query and `router.pathname` for the path (`/my-app/test-app`) in nextJS